# How to transform Pandas DataFrame into MultiIndexed form for a clustermap?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have a dataFrame that is a list of observations, grouped by a 'name' column. I'm having a hard time to turn that into a multiIndex format.

I have something like:

```
    name | ratio | DayOfWeek | HourOfDay
    foo  | 0.7   | Mon       | 0
    foo  | 0.2   | Mon       | 1
    foo  | 0.11  | Mon       | 2
    foo  | 0.45  | Mon       | 3
..
    foo  | 0.2   | Mon       | 23
    foo  | 0.1   | Tue       | 0
    foo  | 0.6   | Tue       | 1
    foo  | 0.2   | Tue       | 2
..
    foo  | 0.1   | Sun       | 23
    bar  | 0.2   | Mon       | 0
    bar  | 0.11  | Mon       | 1
..
```

and so on.

What I want is something that I can use with seaborn clustermaps to show correlation between the 'ratios' of the 'names' by each day (as a whole) and particular hours within days.

e.g. I need something like (unsure if correct, but that's what I tried):

```
                      | foo  | bar | ...
DayOfWeek  HourOfDay  |
Mon        0          | 0.7  | 0.2 | ...
           1          | ...
           2          | ...
...
Tue        0          | 0.1  | ...
           1          | ...
...        2
```

Once I have that I hope to be able to xs() it into slices usable by heatmap / clustermap from seaborn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = df.set_index(['DayOfWeek','HourOfDay','name'])['ratio'].unstack()
print (df)
name                  bar   foo
DayOfWeek HourOfDay            
Mon       0          0.20  0.70
          1          0.11  0.20
          2           NaN  0.11
          3           NaN  0.45
          23          NaN  0.20
Sun       23          NaN  0.10
Tue       0           NaN  0.10
          1           NaN  0.60
          2           NaN  0.20
```

But if duplicates need [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) with some aggregate func like `mean`, `sum`...:

```
print (df)
   name  ratio DayOfWeek  HourOfDay
0   foo   0.70       Mon          0 <- duplicate for same name, DayOfWeek and HourOfDay - 0.7
1   foo   0.90       Mon          0 <- duplicate for same name, DayOfWeek and HourOfDay - 0.9
2   foo   0.20       Mon          1
3   foo   0.11       Mon          2
4   foo   0.45       Mon          3
5   foo   0.20       Mon         23
6   foo   0.10       Tue          0
7   foo   0.60       Tue          1
8   foo   0.20       Tue          2
9   foo   0.10       Sun         23
10  bar   0.20       Mon          0
11  bar   0.11       Mon          1


df = df.pivot_table(index=['DayOfWeek','HourOfDay'], 
                    columns='name', 
                    values='ratio', 
                    aggfunc='mean')
print (df)

name                  bar   foo
DayOfWeek HourOfDay            
Mon       0          0.20  0.80 < (0.7 + 0.9)/2 = 0.8
          1          0.11  0.20
          2           NaN  0.11
          3           NaN  0.45
          23          NaN  0.20
Sun       23          NaN  0.10
Tue       0           NaN  0.10
          1           NaN  0.60
          2           NaN  0.20
```

Alternative with `groupby`:

```
df = df.groupby(['DayOfWeek','HourOfDay','name'])['ratio'].mean().unstack()
print (df)
name                  bar   foo
DayOfWeek HourOfDay            
Mon       0          0.20  0.80 < (0.7 + 0.9)/2 = 0.8
          1          0.11  0.20
          2           NaN  0.11
          3           NaN  0.45
          23          NaN  0.20
Sun       23          NaN  0.10
Tue       0           NaN  0.10
          1           NaN  0.60
          2           NaN  0.20
```